# Errors in testing HTML parsing in free web hosting sites

Tags: android, html-parsing, web-hosting

I needed to test the `html` parsing code of a site. it runs okay in `java` console.. Tried using my3gb.com and x10hosting.. But in both i get the error time-out exception..??

Please suggest a hosting site .The `logcat` shows this in the above sites:

```
 03-03 14:29:35.273: WARN/System.err(517): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
```

Comment: This exception occur when it takes too much time to respond and no reliable for response. Test it its working in browser or not.

Comment: tried testin in wampserver with this code:

Comment: Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://10.0.2.2/Example/index.html).get();
But that shows permission denied exception

Comment: have you declare the permission of internet in androidmanifest.xml

Comment: 03-03 15:25:33.529: WARN/System.err(588): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
03-03 15:25:33.543: WARN/System.err(588):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
03-03 15:25:33.543: WARN/System.err(588):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
03-03 15:25:33.543: WARN/System.err(588):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
03-03 15:25:33.543: WARN/System.err(588):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)

Comment: you are testing on LAN??

Comment: in wampserver using my computer as a server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I guess the solution according to you told to me.

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out.

To test the application in device in LAN. You must do following things.

1) Disable the firewall of system.

2) Your device and server must have on same network.

3) Both must have regular internet connection and make sure you have written right `ip-address` of server which you want to connect.

Comment: ya its now running n d LAN. could u suggest wich free website shud i test it with

Comment: @Royce Raju As you told to me you were getting this exception when you were testing to LAN. So its now working on LAN?

Comment: YES ITS WORKING FINE TENX